# Is there a charge for enabling "Cost Explorer" in AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Does AWS charge for enabling **[Cost Explorer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/ce-enable.html)**  for S3? And does its usage itself cost?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no cost for enabling the cost explorer or to play around with it in the console but to access the data via API calls that costs extra. [Analyzing your costs with Cost Explorer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/ce-what-is.html)

Comment: What's the point in posting the exact same answer as the currently accepted one??

Answer (score 5):

From [Analyzing Your Costs with Cost Explorer - AWS Billing and Cost Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/ce-what-is.html):

> You can view your costs and usage using the Cost Explorer user interface free of charge. You can also access your data programmatically using the Cost Explorer API. Each paginated API request incurs a charge of $0.01. You can't disable Cost Explorer after you enable it.